# Trying to get clientEvents after calling refetchEvents does not return any clientEvents

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I've this scenario:

The calendar loads initially and shows a bunch of events based on multiple event sources. I also have some dropdown boxes that lets the user filter the calendar based on some criteria. But to make sure that I always work off of the initial set of events that were loaded from the event sources, I call the .fullCalendar('refetchEvents') call before I start filtering. I do this by getting the client events (.fullCalendar('clientEvents')). But the problem I have is that when I get the client events after I do a refreshEvents, I get 0 client events, even though I can see a bunch of events on the calendar at that point of time. Am I missing something? Please advise.

Code snippet:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); //commenting this out, gives me the clientEvents
var calEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
alert(calEvents.length + " and " + $.isArray(calEvents)); //get nothing here after refetchEvents
if (ui.checked) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    url: "/Case/CalendarFilterCriteria",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { filterOptions: data, caseId: cavo.currentCaseId },
    success: function (response) {
        //alert($.isArray(response.eventIds));
        $.each(calEvents, function (index, value) {
        //alert(index + " and " + value.id);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (value) {
            var found = 0;
            $.each(response.eventIds, function (index, val) {
                console.log("value " + value.id + " val " + val.id);
                if (value.id === val.id) {
                    console.log("match found");
                    found = 1;
                    return false; //to break the inner .each loop
                }
            })
            console.log("remove " + !found);
            return !found; //if true, the event will be deleted from the calendar
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `refetchEvents` is making an ajax call asynchronously.  Which means that data hasn't necessarily been retrieved when you call `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents')`.